# able to connect to linked server but i cannot select from any table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I have a linked server to a pervasive sql 11 database from my sql server 2012 64bit using ODBC

I am able to see the databases on this server, but when I select * from any table I am getting this error:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "kslap208" returned message "[Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface][Data Record Manager]The MicroKernel cannot find the specified file(Btrieve Error 12)".
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "kslap208" returned message "[Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Unable to open table: aactual.".
Msg 7306, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot open the table ""sbxc003"."aactual"" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "kslap208".
```

How is it possible that I am able to test the connection succesfully and see all the databases; however, I cannot select?

Comment: You might want check your ODBC setting and make sure it was set correctly, the error message "The MicroKernel cannot find the specified file" lead me to think something in setup was wrong

Comment: When you set up your ODBC did you test it? Are you certain that your login gives you access to this table? If you create a linked table in MS Access to this ODBC connection, what tables do you see?

Comment: @SimonWang thank you , but i did test the connecetion and everything seemed fine

Comment: @ElectricLlama thank you for the message. yes i did test the connection was good

Comment: please post a select statement that fails

Comment: @Blam select * from kslap208.sbxc003..aactual

Comment: Only a comment but try select * from kslap208.sbxc003.dbo.aactual (or the owner of the table)

Comment: thank you, i did try that already

Comment: How do you authenticate to linked server?  Does that user have select authority?

Comment: i am succesfully linking to this linked server from a different server with sql server 2005 with the same username and no problems selecting

Comment: its some sort of funny memory issue or something. when i select more than a certain number of columns, i get the catastrophic error, otherwise it works

Comment: @SimonWang its some sort of funny memory issue or something. when i select more than a certain number of columns, i get the catastrophic error, otherwise it works

Comment: @ElectricLlama its some sort of funny memory issue or something. when i select more than a certain number of columns, i get the catastrophic error, otherwise it works

Comment: Sounds like you need to analyse it some more - exactly how many columns before it fails? is it a specific column? does it work if you type select 1 from kslap208.sbxc003..aactual